# I am trying to broadcast messages to specific users from who use my application?

Tags: java, android, networking, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I need to broadcast a message to only specific users.

My idea is may be forwarding with IP address or MAC of wifi, but looks IP is the registered in networks.

I need the message should be delivered to the receiver with any http request from the receiver.

Like in (viber-android application), if someone makes call or send any messages then the messages are delivered instantaneously.

I am searching for that tech they use. If you have any idea about that please reply.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: "Broadcast a message to only specific users" is already a contradiction in terms. Possibly what you are looking for is multicast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking for, but I *think* you want push messaging, in which case [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) is a good option.

Comment: ya exactly like push messaging over IP

Comment: @arnp GCM works over IP, of course...